# Meaning of a Function

Tags: php, c, function, variables, operators

Here is the function I'm not understanding:

```
$year = date("Y");
$leapYear = false;
if((($year%4==0) && ($year%100==0)) || ($year%400==0))
    $leapYear = true;
```

Does that mean that, if the `(($year is divided by 4 but not divided by 100) or (the year is divided by 400))` that is a leap year?

I'm new to PHP, please anyone help me to understand the statements.

Comment: you dont need to do that any more to find a leap year `echo date('L');`

Comment: Change `&&` to `AND` and `||` to `OR`, keep into consideration parenthesis, and you'll clearly see the right expression

Comment: There appears to be a bug.  Shouldn't it say `$year%100!=0`?

Comment: @Nirk yes, it is wrong -- which is why the logic is more complicated than it needs to be as the code is written now.

Comment: Please fix the question to be correct (as nirk said), then we can give you the answer you are really looking for.  As posted, this doesn't detect leap years.  100/200/300 years are NOT leap years, bu your code says they are.

Comment: There's a good chance you're confused by && because the code you posted above is supposed to calculate leap years, but doesn't.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't century years not leap years unless they are divisible by 400?

Comment: @Orangepill yeah, that's what everyone is already talking about

Comment: Why not just use `$leapYear = date("L") == 1`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're likely confused because the code you've provided doesn't find leap years.  Leap years are divisible by 4 but NOT 100.. unless they are also divisible by 400.  If you flip the logic around, it's easier to look at.  If it's divisible by 400, it's a leap year, no matter what.  Otherwise, it's a leap year if it's divisible by 4 and NOT divisible by 100.

```
// pseudocode
if ( year % 400 == 0  || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

You can play around with it and just say:

```
return year % 400 == 0  || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
```

The && means both sides have to be `true` in order for && to return `true`.

Comment: removed by answer as being painfully redundant... spent too much time researching leap year calculations and not enough time looking at the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what is says in pseudo code

```
if(year is divisible by 4 or 100) {
  leapyear = true
} else if (year is divisible by 400) {
  //this will never be hit because it would meet the first case
  leapyear = true
}
```

Comment: why not write what it says?  it's not 4 or 100 -- it only works that way because 100 is divisible by 4.

Comment: Also, this answer isn't very meaningful because the question isn't actually what the person wants to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, your second guess is correct.

```
if((($year % 4==0) && ($year % 100==0)) || ($year % 400==0))
```

means that EITHER of these must be true to be a leap year:

1. `($year%4==0) && ($year%100==0)`
2. `$year%400==0`

So a year is a leap year under these conditions:

- year is divisible  by 4 and divisible by 100

OR

- year is divisible by 400

However, the code you posted is wrong in that it doesn't correctly define a leap year.

A year is a [leap year](http://leap-year-guide.blogspot.com/2011/03/leap-year-calculation.html) if it is divisible by 4, except when it is divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400.  So in your `if` statement the `($year % 100 == 0)` should be `($year % 100 != 0)`

So the proper logic would be this:

```
if ((($year % 4 == 0) && ($year % 100 != 0)) || ($year % 400 == 0))
    $leapYear = true;
```

#### Regarding the `&&`:

`&&` means AND, and the expression `A && B` is either true or false.

By definition, `A && B` is true only if both `A` and `B` are true.  If any of them are false, then `A && B` is false.

Comment: yes, but the question is wrong, so the description is accurate but not really useful.  Leap years aren't divisible by 100 unless they are divisible by 400.